# How can I suppress the printing of "Wide character in print at" with read.xls

Tags: r, excel, gdata

I have Excel file with wide characters; but I don't want the following message to be printed.
My Excel file contains a cell with content:

> “2020-02-06 生化检验三十九项（光谷）:谷丙转氨酶,74IU/L 高; 谷草转氨酶,50IU/L 高; 总蛋白,70.6g/L ;
>   白蛋白,37.6g/L 低; 总胆红素,6.6umol/L ; 直接胆红素,3.1umol/L ; 间接胆红素,3.5umol/L ;
>   总胆汁酸,2.2umol/L ; 血糖,5.87mmol/l ; 尿素氮,4.3mmol/L ; 肌酐,70.5umol/L ;
>   尿酸,306umol/L ; 碱性磷酸酶,53IU/L ; γ-谷氨酰转肽”,

I think this the reason why it issues a red warning message. I will parse this sentence in the following steps so it is acceptable.

```
> library(gdata)

> dtAll <- read.xls("~/Data/365-40.xlsx",stringsAsFactors = F,
+                   verbose=FALSE,encoding ="UTF-8")
Wide character in print at /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/gdata/perl/xls2csv.pl line 327.
Wide character in print at /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/gdata/perl/xls2csv.pl line 327.
Wide character in print at /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/gdata/perl/xls2csv.pl line 327.
Wide character in print at /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/gdata/perl/xls2csv.pl line 327.
```

Comment: Try `suppressMessages(dtAll <- read.xls("~/Data/365-40.xlsx",stringsAsFactors = F, verbose=FALSE,encoding ="UTF-8"))`

Comment: I have just tried that, but it still print the message. it does not work.@AllanCameron

Comment: Are you wedded to using the `gdata` package to read in the file?  You could possibly sidestep the issue by using the `readxl` package (or other alternatives) instead.

Comment: Have you tried `suppressWarnings` as well as `suppressMessages`?

Comment: *readxl* looks a really good package! I will try to use it. BTW, do you know any good package in tidyverse that can read MS word (.doc or .docx) files? @H1;

Comment: There are packages that can be used to read word documents but none in the tidyverse as far as I know.